# Check: Conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose you have three coins. One of them is completely normal, one of them is marked with a color on (exactly) one side and the third one is marked with a color on both sides. Now a coin is selected randomly.  This coin is presented in such a way that only one side is visible. This side is unmarked. How high is the probability that this coin has no mark on both sides?

Can I solve this problem like this ? N means not marked and M means marked. So there a three coins $\{NN,NM,MM\}$ and i want to calculate $P[NN|$at least one side is not marked$]$ with $P[$at least one side is not marked$  \cap NN] = \frac{1}{3}$ and $P[$at least one side is not marked$]$ = $\frac{2}{3}$ so $P[NN|$at least one side is not marked$] = \frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

> Can I solve this problem like this? ... so $P[NN|$at least one side is not marked] = $\frac13$

No. That conditional probability is in fact $\frac12$ - the ratio of the two probabilities $P([NN]$ and at least one side is not marked) to $P($at least one side is not marked).

Moreover, that's not the probability we seek. The way I read it, the conditional probability we're looking at is
$$P[NN|\text{ the random side we're looking at is unmarked}]$$

Comment: Oh i see the problem. $P[$the random side we're looking at is unmarked$] = \frac{1}{3}$ and the and $P[NN \cap $the random side we're looking at is unmarked$] = \frac{1}{3}$, so that would be 1. Where is the mistake?

Comment: That's not a correct evaluation of the first probability. How many unmarked sides are there across all coins? How many total sides?

Comment: sorry,  how silly. So there are 6 sides and 3 unmarked sides so it would be $\frac{1}{2}$ and in total $P[...] = \frac{\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{2}{3}$